# XAML Progressbar in Powershell

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, xaml

I want to have a Progressbar in my Powershell application, which progress is changed during executing the functions. Once one function is ended, I want to move Progressbar a little.

Progressbar is declared in XAML:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="20" 
             Margin="0,672,0,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="754" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
```

Then, I'm trying to change the Progressbar value during event Button_Click:

```
$ProgressBar.Value = 0

Function1   

$ProgressBar.Value = 30

Function2

$ProgressBar.Value = 100
```

I tried this logic using Write-Progress and it works, also tried with non-xaml .Net Powershel implemented in Powershell - with success. Do I need to use Background Jobs? Or maybe there's another solutions.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What exactly happens? Does it hang? Does it not update the progress at all? How did you obtain the reference to `$ProgressBar`

Comment: Here is my reference: $global:ProgressBar = $Window.FindName('ProgressBar'), it update process only at the end - when is 100%. The functions are working rather long (whole process takes about 2 minutes), so there's no possibility, that I didn't notice the progress growing.

Comment: I've checked and it's keepeing the proper value of Progressbar each time. Probably it's only not updating it. Maybe use some function like UpdateLayout() or something like this?

Comment: @mystery-user sounds like something else is running on the main UI thread, which will prevent it from updating the progress bar - you should run it as a background job and see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but this is something that I have been working a lot on lately.  Not exactly sure if this is the case because of the lack of code, but you could try this if your ProgressBar is on a different thread.  It will wait for the dispatcher to have an opening and update the ProgressBar on the UI thread

```
$ProgressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{
    $ProgressBar.Value = 30
}, "Normal")
```

Edit:
Another way to accomplish this task would be using a dispatcherTimer, where you could tell it how often you want the component updated.  This was a resource that helped me understand the basic concept of the DispatcherTimer
https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/a-powershell-clock/